# Error installing STS plugin in Eclipse Neon.2

Tags: eclipse, plugins, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-neon

I use the following Eclipse Neon.2

- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers
- Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)
- Build id: 20161208-0600
- Eclipse path: C:\eclipse-jee-neon

and I tried to install the following Eclipse Plugin (via Marketplace or with drag and install directly from the website)

- Spring Tool Suite (STS) for Eclipse 3.8.3.RELEASE
  and I receive the following error:

[image]

As an alternative I tried the Spring IDE 3.8.3.RELEASE plugin and got exactly the same error.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the following two .jar archives were corrupted:

- com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations_2.5.0.v201504151636.jar
- com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core_2.5.0.v201504151636.jar

The solution (which worked in my case) was:

1. Download the two artifacts manually for example from [University of Kent UKMirror Service](http://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/download.eclipse.org/eclipseMirror/linuxtools/update-docker-1.2/plugins/)
2. Replace the two corrupted artifacts in C:\Users\smo.p2\pool\plugins\ with the manually downloaded ones
3. Reinstall the plugin over the Eclipse Marketplace